# is it possible to load script file to run in the middle of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I know that when a certain condition is true, I'll need to run different scripts, is it possible to load the script dynamically into a function I'm running?

```
$("#container").on("click", "#submit", function(){
    var prodID = $("#productSelect").find(".selected_option").data("product_id");

    //somehow load a script like "validation_" + prodId;

});
```

Or should I manually put all the code into a single function

```
$("#container").on("click", "#submit", function(){
    var prodID = $("#productSelect").find(".selected_option").data("product_id");

    switch (prodID){
       case 1:
       //code for prodID 1
       break;

       case 2:
       //code for prodID 2
       break;

       case 3:
       //code for prodID 3
       break;

    }

});
```

It is just an attempt to keep things a little cleaner looking. I don't know if it's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) ?

Comment: have you considered requirejs?

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend to go with

```
$("#container").on("click", "#submit", function(){
  var prodID = $("#productSelect").find(".selected_option").data("product_id");

  switch (prodID){
   case 1:
   functionForCase1();
   break;

   case 2:
   functionForCase2();
   break;

   case 3:
   functionForCase3();
   break;

  }
});

function functionForCase1(){
   //code for prodID 1
}

function functionForCase2(){
   //code for prodID 2
}

function functionForCase1(){
   //code for prodID 3
}
```

Comment: I see. I think I will go with this idea, yes. Seems better to keep everything in one file anyway. Good point. Thank you.